# How to copy A VCD

Tags: vlc, iso, vcd

I am trying to copy a CD containing mpeg, .dat videos. now I want to transfer it to my notebook through pendrive as there is no CD-rom there.And normally copying the files isnt working,. so how do I do that? I am thinking of creating ab ISO of the VCD and mount that ISO in my notebook. But How do I do this?

Comment: Why is normally copying the files not working? Sounds to me like an issue with the disc.

Answer (score 3):

I had some trouble with VCD/SVCD's and asked here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/253009/how-to-resolve-dd-failure-with-input-output-error-on-multiple-cd-rs

My final solution was to use vcdxrip, which comes from the vcdimager package, but I can't remember if it is installed by default.  Here's the vcdxrip manpage:  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/vcdxrip.1.html

Answer (score 2):

If you know the device corresponding to the CD drive, just type the following into a terminal (substituting the appropriate paths):

```
cat /dev/scd0 > /home/somePath/isoName.iso
```

If you do not know the device corresponding to your CD drive (in the example above it was /dev/scd0), find it by typing the following into a terminal (with the disk in the drive):

```
mount
```

and look for the device mounted on /media/nameOfYourDisk